# RGB LED strip with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, led, mosfet

I am trying to control an RGB LED strip with an Arduino. I have followed the tutorials in both of these websites: 
Using MOSFETs: https://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips?view=all
[image]

Using LED Amplifiers: http://www.instructables.com/id/LED-Strip-Controller-w-LED-Amp-Arduino/
[image]

I have tried both setups and none of them work for me. When I try the setup with the MOSFETs, I am able to control each color but the blue LEDs are dimmer than the red and green, and therefore I can't mix any colors with blue.

When I try the LED Amplifiers, I am not able to control any light at all. Only the blue LEDs light up but the red and green dont. Also the blue LEDs stay ON the whole time and the only way to turn them off is to disconnect them from the DC power source. 
What am I doing wrong?